# Unable to open hgt downloaded from dds.cr.usgs.gov

Tags: gdal, srtm, hgt

I downloaded a SRTM hgt file from https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version1/SRTM30/w100n40/w100n40.dem.zip, after unzipping I am not able to open it in QGIS or even `gdalinfo`. I downloaded other hgt files from this other site http://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/ and can open them without trouble; I read the file names have to do with the CRS of the file, so I played a little with the one that doesn't open, trying to follow the names of the one that does open, but not even this way I could read it; the one that opens starts with latitude (`N19W097.hgt`) whereas the one that does not open starts with the longitude (`w100n40.hgt`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, me too:

```
$ ls
w100n40.hgt
$ gdalinfo w100n40.hgt 
ERROR 4: `w100n40.hgt' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'w100n40.hgt'.
```

I had a look at the folder where that problematic HGT file came from...

https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version1/SRTM30/w100n40/

and there's a bunch of other stuff. I wonder if the "HDR.zip" file is useful, maybe it has some sort of essential header info. So I downloaded it and unzipped it. So now I have:

```
$  ls
W100N40.HDR  w100n40.hgt
```

And `gdalinfo` goes.....

```
$ gdalinfo w100n40.hgt 
Driver: EHdr/ESRI .hdr Labelled
Files: w100n40.hgt
       W100N40.HDR
Size is 4800, 6000
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-100.000000000000000,39.999999999999993)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333333330,-0.008333333333330)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-100.0000000,  40.0000000) 
Lower Left  (-100.0000000, -10.0000000) 
Upper Right ( -60.0000000,  40.0000000) 
Lower Right ( -60.0000000, -10.0000000) 
Center      ( -80.0000000,  15.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=4800x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
```

woah! cool. I wonder what's in that HDR file:

```
$ strings W100N40.HDR 
BYTEORDER      M
LAYOUT       BIL
NROWS         6000
NCOLS         4800
NBANDS        1
NBITS         16
BANDROWBYTES         9600
TOTALROWBYTES        9600
BANDGAPBYTES         0
NODATA        -9999
ULXMAP        -99.99583333333334
ULYMAP        39.99583333333333
XDIM          0.00833333333333
YDIM          0.00833333333333
```

So it looks like this is a "EHdr/ESRI .hdr Labelled" format file and need the HDR and the HGT, unlike the other .HGT files which are SRTM HGT files:

```
$ gdalinfo N53W001.hgt
Driver: SRTMHGT/SRTMHGT File Format
```

Not sure about the other files in that download folder - they might have the projection and other useful metadata. Grab the lot and see! I see they have weird line ending characters so when I use `cat` on them I only see the last line (which is why I used `strings` above`).

If you go another level or two up you can drill down to the documentation which describes the files in that folder:

https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version1/SRTM30/SRTM30_Documentation

Lessons: nose around your download sites for more info; don't think a file extension reliably tells you what a file is.

Comment: I was confused because the other higher resolution (90 m) files in the same site do not have these additional files; anyway I was looking for the 30 m files (which I downloaded from the other link) but they're not in the dds site